# Add field in swagger ui using drf-yasg

Tags: django, drf-yasg

My code is hosted [here](https://github.com/eadaradhiraj/DjangoJWT/). It uses `drf-yasg`, `jwt` and the `django rest framework`. I am trying to set up a patch method to have the user edit his task. The code in a nutshell is as follows

```
def get_payload(request):
    token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
    if not token:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated!')

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated!')
    return payload


class TaskView(APIView):
    pk = openapi.Parameter('pk', openapi.IN_QUERY,
                             description="field you want to order by to",
                             type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER)
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        request_body=openapi.Schema(
            manual_parameters=[pk],
            type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
            properties={
                'taskname': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, description='Add taskname'),
                'completion': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_BOOLEAN, description='completion'),
            }
        )
    )
    def patch(self, request, pk):
        payload = get_payload(request=request)
        task = Tasks.objects.filter(id=pk, username=payload['username']).first()
        serializer = TaskSerializer(task, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

However, the swagger ui does not display the field for `pk`. I can see the sample body but the field for `pk` is missing.
[image]

How do I add the field for `pk` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `pk` parameter in urls config as well:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view()),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view()),
    path('user/', UserView.as_view()),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view()),
    path('task/<int:pk>/', TaskView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but for the get request I need to retrieve a list and this interferes with it. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak if you want to handle list and details views you need to create two different classes like here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views Or you can use viewset to combine all logic inside one class: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/